# How to set the health-check-type of an auto-scaling-group created by elastic-beanstalk as ELB programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

I just followed this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/devops/using-the-elastic-beanstalk-eb-cli-to-create-manage-and-share-environment-configuration/) to learn how to use `eb` command.

One thing I want to do is to modify the `Health Check Type` of the auto scaling group created by Elastic-Beanstalk to `ELB`. But I just can't find how to do it.

Here's what I have done:

1. Change the `Health Check Type` of the environment `dev-env` to `ELB` through the AWS console.
2. Use `eb config save dev-env --cfg my-configuration` to save the configuration file locally.
3. The `ELB` health check type doesn't appear inside `.elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/my-configuration.cfg.yml` file. This means that I must specify the health check type somewhere else.

Then I find another [article](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer/wiki/Elastic-Beanstalk-Tips-and-Tricks) saying that you can put the health check type inside `.ebextensions` folder.

So I make a modification to [eb-python-flask](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-python-flask.git), which is the example of the [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/devops/using-the-elastic-beanstalk-eb-cli-to-create-manage-and-share-environment-configuration/).

[Here's my modification](https://github.com/lyenliang/eb-python-flask/commit/322417453a1ad1003d123e429e8b66e57917a00f) of [eb-python-flask](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-python-flask.git).

I thought that running `eb config put prod`, and `eb create prod2-env --cfg prod` with [my eb-python-flask](https://github.com/lyenliang/eb-python-flask) would create an environment whose health-check-type of the auto scaling group is `ELB`. But I was wrong. The health check type created by the `eb` commands is still `EC2`.

Anyone know how to set the health check type programmatically?

I don't want to set it through AWS console. It's inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eb create prod3-env --cfg prod` command uses git `HEAD` version to create a zip file to upload to elastic beanstalk.

This can be discovered through `eb create --verbose prod3-env --cfg prod` command, which shows you a verbose output.

The reason I failed to run my own [configuraion](https://github.com/lyenliang/eb-python-flask/commit/322417453a1ad1003d123e429e8b66e57917a00f#diff-7260b09514179ea5985b037f39ac6507) is that I didn't commit the config file to git before running `eb create prod3-env --cfg prod`.

After committing the changes of the code, I successfully deployed an Auto Scaling Group whose Health Check Type is `ELB`.

Answer (score 0):

An ebextension like the below will do it:

`Resources:
    AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
      Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
      Properties:
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300`

I use the path .ebextensions/autoscaling.config

Comment: I've tried this [configuration](https://github.com/lyenliang/eb-python-flask/commit/322417453a1ad1003d123e429e8b66e57917a00f). But it failed. Is there anything else that I have to do after adding the ebextension?